# Displaying custom markers (svg/png) in Google Maps v3 in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8.1, marker

I have a page that displays nearby places of interest for a given location in Google Maps V3. It uses custom svg images for the markers.

The code works in Chrome on Android, Safari in iOS, and in IE in Windows Phone 8.0. After updating my test phone to Windows Phone 8.1, the custom markers stopped showing. (It also doesn't work in jsFiddle.) Windows Phone 8.1 shows Google's default marker just fine.
Here is the code that creates the markers:

```
placeService.nearbySearch(kynFilterReq, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        kynMarker = [];
      console.log(results);
      for (i in results) {
        var kynIndex = getKYNFilterIndex(results[i].types[0]);
        var position = results[i].geometry.location;
        kynMarker [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: position,
          draggable: false,
          crossOnDrag: false,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          zIndex: 100,
          icon: { url: selImgURL,
                 size: new google.maps.Size(27.5,27.5),
                 origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                 anchor: new google.maps.Point(14, 14),
                 scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25,25),
               },
          // icon: selImgURL,
          kynType: kynIndex,
          title: results[i].name
        });

        //add an infowindow
        google.maps.event.addListener(kynMarker[i], 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent('<div class="map-overlay"><h5>'+this.title+'</h5></div>');
          infowindow.open(map, this);
          $('.gm-style-iw').css('overflow','hidden');
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in mobile IE11? I expect the former, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help in resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4604739/test/index.html

On a side note, it would be nice to figure out how to get the code to work in jsFiddle as well.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anishbenji/amw5mx9a/

Thanks,
Anish